# How to display splash screen from MSI (WIndows Installer) installation?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, splash-screen

I have developed installation of my application using InstallShield. When installation is built as a single self extracting executable, then everything works fine and splash screen is displayed while setup.exe is launched. However, when I changed the installation to be of type Downloader (which means two files setup.exe and setup.msi will be created separately) and I launch the MSI the splash screen is not displayed.
How this can be implemented, Please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI doesn't have the ability to display a splash screen. As the file is getting processed by msiexec it will just show the default "Preparing to install..." message [image: default MSI extraction dialog]

If you want to display a splash screen it will need to be done by a separate bootstrapper.